# Why my static method value did not appear in my ejs page

Tags: sequelize.js, ejs

this is from the models

```
    static status(){
      this.count()
        .then(data => {
          return data;
        })
    }
```

I wanna take the value of static status() to my ejs page

this is in my controller but when i run the code the value didn't appear

```
static home(req, res){
    // console.log(req.query);
    let title = req.query.title;
    let artist = req.query.artist;
    let temp = {};
    if(title){
      temp.name = {[Op.iLike]: '%' + title + '%'}
    }else{
      temp.name = {[Op.iLike]: '%' + '%'}
    }
    if(artist){
      temp.artist = {[Op.iLike]: '%' + artist + '%'};
    }else{
      temp.artist = {[Op.iLike]: '%' + '%'}
    }
    // console.log(temp);
    Art.findAll({
      order: [['date', 'desc']], 
      where: {name: temp.name, artist: temp.artist}
    })
      .then(data => {
        // console.log(data[0])
        res.render('home', {
          data,
          Art,
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.send(err);
      })
  }
```

this is in my ejs page
<%= Art.status() %>

Comment: please don't use images. use actual code.

Comment: hi imerla i already fix the question

Answer (score 0):

In `status` you don't return a value from an async `count` call, you better mark this function as async and simply return value right from `count`:

```js
async static status(){
  return this.count()
}
```